# Blender file Mac to Window

Tags: edit-mode

I'm a student and often it happens to me to work at school where we use macs and at home where I use my computer which has Windows 10 installed. Today I opened at home a file I started at school and as soon as I tried to edit an object in edit mode it seemed bugged. I tried to search some solutions online but found nothing. Everytime I tried to enter edit mode the object would become darker and magenta and cyan lines would pop out from faces and/or edges in their center. I tried to change the graphic settings CPU to GPU or viceversa, I also tried modifying the cycles setting but it didn't work out. I then realized that I've been working on two different operating system so I opened a new file and just copied my work on there. Is it normal? Or have I corrupted something?

Here is how it looked like.

[image]